# Rigorous proof that the monotone sequence diverges.

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies:
$|f'(x)|\le 1 \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $a_n$ be a monotonic sequence s.t: $f(a_n)=C+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.(C is a constant).
Now I want to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\infty$.

According to the definition I need to show that for each $M>0$ there exists an index $N$ s.t for each $n>N$ we have $a_n>M$.

Now from what is known I know that I can use Lagrange theorem i.e:
$|\frac{f(a_n)-f(0)}{a_n}|\le 1$, and then get: $||C-f(0)|-1/n | \le |a_n|$.
But I am not sure how to finish this proof?

Comment: How does the function depend on the value of $a_n$?  As written, it is not clear that $f$ is well-defined.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: $f$ is any function with $|f'(x)|\le 1$.

Comment: That's the question that I got from a student as is, that I am tutoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Try using $f(a_{n-1})$ instead of $f(0)$.

Comment: So I get: $|a_n-a_{n-1}| \ge |\frac{(2n-1)}{n(n-1)}$, I am not sure I see how to continue from here?

Comment: Now notice that the problem reduces to determining that the sum of that value on the RHS of your inequality is divergent. If you need more help, feel free to comment again.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist - Remove the absolute value from the l.h.s (allowed because $a_n$ is monotone) and argue that the distance between $a_{2n}$ to $a_n$, (say) is larger than a partial sum of the harmonic series..

Comment: OK, I see the light... :-)

Comment: so $a_n=\sum^n_{i=1}(a_i-a_{i-1})+a_0\ge \sum^n_{i=1}\frac{(2n-1)}{n(n-1)}+a_0\ge \sum^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{i} +a_0.$